# Redirect map work

Tags: sxa

How to check `redirect map` programming functionality in `Sitecore SXA`?

Here, I am taking about Sitecore `.dll` which are using for redirect map. Is there any path in `Content editor` to check the assembly path of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with checking `App_Config\Modules\SXA` config files.

You will easily find `Sitecore.XA.Feature.Redirects.config` in `Feature` folder there.

In that file you can see

```
<processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Redirects.Pipelines.HttpRequest.RedirectMapResolver, Sitecore.XA.Feature.Redirects" resolve="true">
    <CacheExpiration>720</CacheExpiration>
</processor>
```

It means you have to check `Sitecore.XA.Feature.Redirects.dll` and `RedirectMapResolver` class to find out how redirect maps works in SXA.

Comment: Where we can override assemply name for this if we would like to update something ?

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/use-a-patch-file-to-customize-the-sitecore-configuration.html